# How to redirect with .htaccess file in wamp server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, wamp

Hey guys im trying to prevent that anybody can access the homepage of my wamp server.

So if somebody types `www.example.com` then it shows the homepage of the wamp server.

But if somebody tries to enter the `www.example.com` site then it should be redirected to `www.example.com/moodle`

This is what i tried so far in the .htaccess file:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/moodle$ [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /moodle [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

It seems like its creating an infinitive loop.

Here is my whole .htaccess file:

```
# On some PHP servers it may help if this file is copied
# to the main moodle directory and renamed .htaccess
#
# As soon as you do this, check your web site.  Is it
# still working OK?  If you are getting a "configuration
# error" then you may need to enable overrides by editing
# the main httpd.conf for Apache and in the main server
# or virtual server area, adding something like:
#
# <Directory /web/moodle>
#     AllowOverride All
# </Directory>
#

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^((?!moodle/).*)$ moodle/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>

### Firstly, if you are using Apache 2, you need the following
### three lines to allow Apache to pass a PATH_INFO variable
### correctly for URLs like http://server/file.php/arg1/arg2

<IfDefine APACHE2>
    AcceptPathInfo on
</IfDefine>

### Secondly, you can define the default files in the Moodle
### directories as follows:

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

### Thirdly, set up some PHP variables that Moodle needs

php_flag file_uploads            1
php_flag short_open_tag          1
php_flag session.auto_start      0
php_flag session.bug_compat_warn 0

### Fourthly, sometimes Apache limits the size of uploaded files
### (this is a separate limit to the one in PHP, see below).
### The setting here turns off this limitation

LimitRequestBody 0


### These are optional - you may not want to override php.ini
### To enable them, remove the leading hash (#)

#php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
#php_value post_max_size 2M
#php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 7200


### You can change the following line to point to the
### error/index.php file in your Moodle distribution.
### It provides a form which emails you (the admin)
### about 404 errors (URL not found).

#ErrorDocument 404 http://example.org/moodle/error/index.php


### People have reported that these can help in some cases
### (unusual) when you see errors about undefined functions

#php_value auto_prepend_file none
#php_value include_path .
```

Comment: Setup Virtual Hosts as in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^((?!moodle/).*)$ moodle/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: The fact that you're getting 403 means it is trying to load `/www/www.example.com` (which is not in my suggested rule)

Comment: It is loading the homepage of the wamp server which is /www/index.php but i get the 403 error because ive denied the access to this file...

Comment: If it is just loading `/www/index.php` then why it is giving you 403? What happens when you directly open `http://domain.com/moodle/`?

Comment: Again: Because i denied the acces to the file in my httpd.conf file.
when i directly open my /moodle directory it opens my moodle learning portal as desired....

Comment: And once again if as per you request is not going to `www.example.com` folder then why is denying anything inside that directory will cause 403? What if your rename `www.example.com` folder to something else and retest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99958/discussion-between-anubhava-and-cortana).

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
  Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.php?
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/?
  RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php?$ http://www.example.com/moodle$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: should I put the .htaccess file in the /www folder or in the /www/moodle folder?